# CSS select a specific image from multiple images

Tags: css-selectors

How can I select an image from multiple images?

For example I got these images:

```html
<img src="smiley1.gif">
<img src="smiley2.gif">
<img src="smiley3.gif">
<img src="smiley4.gif" alt="Smiley face">
<img src="smiley5.gif" alt="Smiley face">
<img src="smiley6.gif" alt="Smiley face">
```

I can select the first 3 with the :not selector:

```css
img:not([alt])
```

Thought I can select the 2nd one like this:

```css
img:not([alt]):nth-child(2)
```

But it does not work. How can I select the 2nd one for example?

Comment: Why aren't you using a specific id ?

Comment: I can't change the html, only css.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, but looks like it is impossible to do it only with css selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:nth-of-type(n)`

```css
img:not([alt]):nth-of-type(2) {
background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<img src="smiley1.gif">
<img src="smiley2.gif">
<img src="smiley3.gif">
<img src="smiley4.gif" alt="Smiley face">
<img src="smiley5.gif" alt="Smiley face">
<img src="smiley6.gif" alt="Smiley face">
```

Comment: it won't work if you change the order of elements,it always selects 2nd element from top

Answer (score 0):

You can go by adjunct sibling selector , 
This is in case you would want to select any thing regardless if it is has an alt or not.

*The alt i put is only to check out the selector so i'll have something to place a background on.

HTML :

```
  <img src="smiley1.gif" alt="1">
  <img src="smiley2.gif" alt="2">
  <img src="smiley3.gif" alt="3">
  <img src="smiley4.gif" alt="4">
  <img src="smiley5.gif" alt="5">
  <img src="smiley6.gif" alt="6">
```

CSS:

```
  img{
     background: red;
 }

 img + img {
     background: yellow;
}

img + img + img{
      background: green;
}

img + img + img + img{
    background: pink;
}

img + img + img + img + img{
    background: blue;
}

img + img + img + img + img + img{
   background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('img').not('[alt]').eq(1); //selects 2nd element which is does not have "alt"
    x.css('border-color', 'red');
});
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="smiley1.gif">
<img src="smiley2.gif">
<img src="smiley3.gif">
<img src="smiley4.gif" alt="Smiley face">
<img src="smiley5.gif" alt="Smiley face">
<img src="smiley6.gif" alt="Smiley face">
```

It works even if you change the order of elements.